# Javascript if else statements issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My task is "If the value (.val()) of the .message-box is equal to an empty string it will display a red border on the textarea. Else it will display the message and hide the textarea." 
Message box border don't get red if i leave it empty and not displaying written message. What's wrong ?
[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHhAz.jpg)

Comment: Put the code in your question, images of code helps no one

Comment: Make your effort first  and write some code.Then post the code if not working

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new here.
Mika A. solved it, thanks for him.

Comment: Remember that `=` is for assignment. Also paste code is better than picture, better yet, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use == instead of = in the test (=== is even often recommended )

Answer (score 1):

in the if block, try

```
$("#text").css("outline", "solid 2px red");
```

also, check Mika A.'s answer.